# How convert hex number to decimal in solidity?

Tags: solidity, hex, decimals

I would like to convert a hex number to decimal.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/47472/integer-to-hexadecimal-number?rq=1

Comment: Hi AmiraliSahraei! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! What are you trying to achieve? What types are involved to do the conversion in solidity?

Answer (score -1):

Here's how you can do it:

```
const { utils, BigNumber } = require("ethers);

const largeNumber = BigNumber.from(0x3eef
0f128b45c7eef) // write your hex number inside the bracket
console.log(largeNumber)
console.log(largeNumber.toString()) // if you want to see the bignumber.
```

You can now take it a step further by converting the bignumber (largeNumber) to decimal like so:

```
const toDecimal = utils.formatEther(largeNumber);
console.log(toDecimal)
```

Note
Note that ethers version 6 beta has been throwing some errors. Instead, install ether version 5.7.2 - npm install ethers@5.7.4

Comment: The question explicitly asks how to do it in solidity.

Comment: That's Solidity - if you don't know.

Comment: This isn't solidity `const { utils, BigNumber } = require("ethers")`.

Comment: Run it in a solidity environment and see if it will run or throw an error.

Comment: It errors out in Remix *ParserError: Expected identifier but got '{'*.